# HuggingFace pipeline for feature-extraction to extract CLS embedding in a SequenceClassification

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I would like to use the inference pipeline to extract the [CLS] embedding. This is my code without the pipeline:

```
model = CamembertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("path")

for chunk in tqdm(list(chunked(my_data, 64))):
    X = tokenizer(chunk, truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=512, return_tensors='pt')
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**X, output_hidden_states=True)
        last_hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states[-1]
        all_cls_embed = last_hidden_states[:, 0, :]
```

But I want to use something like this for prediction:

```
pipe = pipeline(model=model, task="feature-extraction", tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0)
```

But since I use a SequenceClassification model, the features are the logits of the classification layer. I can't use the BertModel alone because it doesn't add the [CLS] token. How can I do ? Thank you.